# R most common string value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe looks like this, with NA values

| id | cat1 | cat2 | cat3 | cat4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | banana | banana | orange |
| 2 | orange | banana | apple | orange |
| 3 | apple | NA | NA | orange |
| 4 | orange | banana | apple | NA |

Each id is expected to have a common categories. so the table shall look like:

| id | cat |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | banana |
| 2 | orange |
| 3 | NA |
| 4 | NA |

is there a simple way using base R? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `Mode` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/3962914)

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  x <- na.omit(x)
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

and apply it to every row.

```
cbind(df[1], cat = apply(df[-1], 1, Mode))

#  id    cat
#1  1 banana
#2  2 orange
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:2, cat1 = c("apple", "orange"), cat2 = c("banana", 
"banana"), cat3 = c("banana", "apple"), cat4 = c("orange", "orange"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: this method doesn't work though on rows with NA value

Comment: In the function you can write the first line as `x <- na.omit(x)`.

Comment: thanks.  it takes the first value as the result if there is no common string.

Comment: @user9776841 Please update your post to include all the relevant edge cases that your data can take and show expected output for it. It is difficult to generalise an answer when you just show 2 most simple cases. Also it is usually better if you add data using `dput` (as I have at the bottom of my answer) which we can copy and also get unambiguous format of your data.

Comment: ach ok, got it thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[, .(cat = names(tail(sort(table(na.omit(unlist(.SD)))), 1))), id]
```

gives

```
   id    cat
1:  1 banana
2:  2 orange
```

---

A base R option with `apply`

```
cbind(
  df[1],
  cat = apply(
    df[-1],
    1,
    function(x) names(tail(sort(table(na.omit(unlist(x)))), 1))
  )
)
```

gives

```
  id    cat
1  1 banana
2  2 orange
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = 1:2, cat1 = c("apple", "orange"), cat2 = c("banana",
"banana"), cat3 = c("banana", "apple"), cat4 = c("orange", "orange"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: this method doesn't work when rows have empty value (NA). the result filters them out.

Comment: @user9776841 See update with `na.omit`

Comment: it still filters na values in the result.

Comment: that apply can be cleaned up a bit `function(x) names(sort(-table(na.omit(x)))[1])`

Comment: @rawr yes, exactly! Thanks!

Comment: @user9776841 Could you provide dummy data with `NA` as you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>% count(id, value) %>% 
     group_by(id) %>% 
            summarise(cat = value[which.max(n)])
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id cat   
  <int> <chr> 
1     1 banana
2     2 orange
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
  transmute(id, cat = pmap_chr(.[-1], ~ Mode(c(...))))
#  id    cat
#1  1 banana
#2  2 orange
```

where

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  x <- na.omit(x)
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:2, cat1 = c("apple", "orange"), cat2 = c("banana",
"banana"), cat3 = c("banana", "apple"), cat4 = c("orange", "orange"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```